# Multi-class classification neural networks... I'm confused

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

Maybe its the big words, maybe its all the numbers and equations. Let me start with what I do know and what I'm trying to do.

I understand that that in a neural network I have a node that sends information to another node and so on. I understand that in a Multi-class classification Neural Network that I'm trying to optimize a node or nodes with features and to do this that I need to train. Now whether or not what I understand is correct... lets move on

What I'm trying to do is understand a problem for class I'm trying to answer. The question simply asks me to design an algorithm for a Multi-Class classification Neural Network that has at least 10^5 features and then I need to train it at least 10^9 times.

Here is my current thought process on solving this. This is super easy in theory I'll scale this down to the fewest nodes for a simple explanation. First I have an input node and my goal is to reach an output node. The single input node has a shite-ton of features and then I put all those 10^5 some features through 10^9 trains and then send it all back to an output node. To look something like this:

[image: Not an literal representation of 10^5 features and 10^9 training sessions]

Is there anything wrong with this algorithm? 
Does what I suggest actually work?
Do I understand this properly?
I'm not sure it should be so easy as I described, please explain how I'm wrong and what I don't get if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Usually neural networks are designed like this. The nodes are separated in several layers. The first layer is the input layer and there is one input node per feature. The last layer is the output layer and this has one node per class you want to learn. In the simplest case there is only on layer inbetween, called the hidden layer. If you have several hidden layers they are called deep neural networks.

Here is an example neural network for [classifying digits](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/):
[image: a neural network to detect numbers in images]

When you train a neural network you first classify the sample by going forward through the network and then go through the network again backwards and modify the weights to shift the result slightly in the correct direction. This is called [backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation).

You should probably look at some examples and tutorial to get more familiar with these concepts. [This](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/) one for example.